# Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Double>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'

Tags: c, swift, macos

I'm working with an external C library in Swift for OS X. I get a value cda, which is defined in C as a `double*` (it is a pointer to a double array).

When importing into Swift, it recognizes the type as UnsafeMutablePointer. I'm trying to convert this pointer and the count into a double array. Here's the code that I'm using (assume arrlen is the correct count of the array):

```
let doublearrptr = UnsafePointer<Double>(cda)
let xptarr = UnsafeBufferPointer<Double>(start: doublearrptr, count:arrlen)
```

However, when compiling this code fragment, I get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafePointer<Double>' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<_>'
```

I'm relatively new to Swift, but I'm fairly certain that I can't convert to `UnsafePointer<_>`. I tried converting to `UnsafePointer<Void>`, but that got the same error. Swift does recognize that `cda` is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>`.

Comment: When you say "it recognizes the type as UnsafeMutablePointer", do you mean that it recognizes it as a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It recognises the double.

Comment: Can you isolate and post code that does not depend on the library? (e.g. declare a C double array, and attempt to convert it to a Swift `Array<Double>`) and show which line is producing the error? The code you posted seems OK.

Comment: I'll work on that- in the meantime, I did: `print(cda.dynamicType)` and got out `UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>` - I would imagine that if the problem was with the C array, I'd get an error at runtime, not at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was able to solve it, albeit in a roundabout way.

I created a new function convert and used it:

```
func convertArr<T>(count: Int, data: UnsafePointer<T>) -> [T] {

    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: count)
    return Array(buffer)
}
...
let doublearrptr = UnsafePointer<Double>(cda)
let arr = convertArr(Int(shobjarrlen), data: doublearrptr)
```

For some reason this works but not the original syntax...

I'm still open to getting answers from *why* my original syntax didn't work.

Comment: Wow, good find. Completely agree that your original code should have been fine. I was having the same issue - to me this looks very much like a bug in Swift.