# Converting Objective-C / C callback code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, c, swift, callback, typedef

I'm currently converting some older Objective-C code to Swift and I'm stuck at some C stuff.

I do have an internal API which expects a callback function.

```
DoSomethingWithCallback(myCallbackType callback);
```

The callback type is specified

```
typedef void(*myCallbackType)(struct customStruct *);
```

In my Objective-C / C code I just added a

```
static void functionThatActsAsCallback(struct customStruct *myStruct) {
 ..
}
```

and could call everything with a

```
DoSomethingWithCallback(functionThatActsAsCallback);
```

I've tried to convert this to Swift by creating the the callback function

```
func functionThatActsAsCallback(myStruct: UnsafePointer<customStruct>) -> Void {

}
```

and tried to do the call via

```
DoSomeThingWithCallback(functionThatActsAsCallback)
```

which results in an error

> Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer) -> Void' to argument type 'myCallbackType!'

I'm not quite sure why this error occurs and how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for any hint

Comment: There are few SO posts describing similar problems: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244438/cannot-convert-value-of-type-unsafepointerdouble-to-expected-argument-type), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626410/how-do-you-convert-a-unsafemutablepointervoid-to-uint8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check how your types and functions are imported into Swift, before using them.

If you have all types and functions declared in a single .h file:

- Wait for Xcode to successfully index your project.
  (You may need to comment out error lines.)
- Open the .h file in Xcode editor.
- Click four square icon at the top left of the editor pane and choose "Generated Interface".

I could have gotten this with my sample project:

```
public typealias myCallbackType = @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<customStruct>) -> Void

public func DoSomethingWithCallback(callback: myCallbackType!)
```

(You may find this with Cmd-clicking on the imported type name or function name.)

So, your issue is caused by type mismatching with `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer`. Modify your callback function as:

```
func functionThatActsAsCallback(myStruct: UnsafeMutablePointer<customStruct>) -> Void {

}
```

And call the `DoSomethingWithCallback` function as:

```
DoSomethingWithCallback(functionThatActsAsCallback)
```

(Match letter cases.)

---

Defining your closure with:

```
let functionThatActsAsCallback: myCallbackType = {myStruct->Void in

}
```

helps you find the parameter type inferred by Swift.